# How to jump one page to another page using HTML and JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html

I want to jump one page to another page using HTML. I have 2 pages. In first page I have one textbox. If I enter any value in that `textbox`, I want to jump on second page. Here `windows.location.href` function will not work. I am using the following code,

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input', function(){    
    var options = $('datalist')[0].options;     
    for (var i=0;i<options.length;i++){
       if (options[i].value == $(this).val()) 
         {alert($(this).val());  
         window.scrollTo(1,2);
         }
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="default" list="languages" placeholder="Group Name">
  
  <datalist id="languages">
  <option value="ADMIN GROUP">
    <option value="INSPECTION GROUP">
    <option value="MANAGER GROUP">
    <option value="USER GROUP">
    <option value="GROUP 1">
    <option value="GROUP 2">
    <option value="GROUP 3">
    <option value="GROUP 4">
    <option value="GROUP 5">
    <option value="GROUP 6">
  </datalist>
```

Here I am using `windows.scrollTo()` function for jumping one page to another. But it is not working. Please help me How can I jump "page1" to "page2" using `HTML`.

Comment: Are `page1` and `page2` HTML files or anchors?

Comment: you are having 2 html pages or 1 html page having 2 divs? if you have 2 html pages you have to use `window.location.href`

Comment: I have 2 screens. If I change any value in in first screen, at that time itself I want to move on second screen. Both have same URL. Thats what I ask jumping one page to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set ID for both screens page1 and page2

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function(){    
    var options = $('datalist')[0].options;     
    for (var i=0;i<options.length;i++){
       if (options[i].value == $(this).val()) 
         {alert($(this).val());  
         $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#page2').offset().top }, "slow");
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: does div with id page2 exist on page?

Answer (score 0):

Well if there are external sites, you have to add the location.
You can also add the anchor if its on the same page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#languages").change(function() {
            location = $("#languages option:selected").val();
            location.href = location;
        });
    });
```

```html
<form>
  
  <select id="languages">
 
    <option value="/site1.html">site 1</option>
    <option value="/site2.html">site 2</option>
    
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Only one HTML page. The second one is Applicationcraft design. From there No html and css codes. I want to jump !st html screen to second applicationcraft screen.

Comment: It's quite hard to understand you. Well you can also add anchors .
Like <section id="firstscreen"> and then in value just add value="#firstscreen" etc.

Answer (score 0):

CSS
a.hiddenLink {visibility:hidden; display:none;}

In Page1.html

write a function to handle the onblur of your text box and there have the below line of code 

    document.getElementById("page2Link").click();

add an anchor tag  with href="page2.html" id="page2Link" class="hiddenLink"

In Page2.html

add an anchor tag with href="page1.html" class="hiddenLink"